# How do I test my .NET applications and how to I implement a tests suites?

Tags: .net, automated-tests

I am programming a MUD game in .NET for fun in my spare time.

I would like to know the efficient way to test my application to see if there are "unused" objects
remaining when I thought they were destroyed successfully when running the game for a few hours. Any tips?

Also, I consider myself of intermediate level in .NET (more specifically VB.NET),
and I would like to know if there is an easy way to implement a "Tests Suites" solution for an established program? Is that plugin/library/what free?

I am using VB.NET 2008 Express.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NUnit**](http://www.nunit.com/) is a free automated unit test framework for .NET.

Comment: How hard is the implementation as I've never implemented any unit test framework before ? Also, do unit test framework provide statistics like the number of objects in memory or I must use something else for that ?

Comment: It's pretty easy to get started with. It won't keep track of objects left in memory, though. For that, you would need something like a memory profiler.

Comment: What is difficult about unit testing is how easy it is to write integration tests instead. That said, nunit is fairly easy to use for writing integration tests and there are multiple test runners, both independent and integrated into IDE´s--which won´t help you here--and integrated into build servers such as team city, which has a free version and isn´t too hard to implement even for a hobby project.